# Sticky Element catching on down scroll and catching on up scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky side bar and right now using js I have it catching and staying fixed t a certain point. But then when I scroll back up I need it to catch and not go further then its starting point.
This is my code so far.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
  $el = $('.why_social'); 
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 735 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
  $('.why_social').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-62px'}); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle using your jQuery code : http://jsfiddle.net/jfeEL/1/ .Now tell what change in the output do you want?

Comment: I appreciate this but it does not seem to be functioning how I want it. I dont think the area is big enough to see the example. If I have something that starts at 500px down the page. And once the top of the page reaches it I want it to stick and continue down with the page. But then I scroll up past 500 at like 490 I want it to stay where it started at 500px

Comment: So can you make a fiddle which shows your current output and then tell what change you require in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have to add an opposite check.  This should get you started.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    $el = $('.why_social'); 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 735 && $el.css('position') !== 'fixed') { 
        $('.why_social').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-62px'}); 
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 735 && $el.css('position') === 'fixed') {  {
        $('.why_social').css({'position': ''}); // remove `position: fixed;`
    }
});
```

Btw: If you've not got your heart set on a custom solution, you could see if [Bootstrap's Affix Plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) meets your needs.  You can get the source code at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/affix.js and that other link will take you to the documentation on how to use it.  All you should have to do is add `.affix { position: fixed; }` to your CSS.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work now, only thing is the element flickers now on scroll. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Michael Oh, yeah, true.  Try replacing `else` with `if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 735 && $el.css('position') === 'fixed')`.  Also, if this answer works, I'd appreciate an accept. ;)

Comment: Sorry I an novice with js. I know this is wrong.   $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    $el = $('.why_social'); 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 735 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
        $('.why_social').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-62px'}); 
  
    }
       if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 735 && $el.css('position') === 'fixed')
    }
});

Comment: @Michael No problem, I'll edit my answer to show you more clearly what I mean.  I can't format the code as nicely in a comment.